# wait until a download completes before calling a function in clojure

Tags: java, selenium, post, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am using a webdriver to navigate to a webpage and download a json file.  I need to wait for completion (or failure, at which I will give the user a message) for the file to download before I can call the function that will pull in the data to the program.  Is there anything I can use in the clojure or java ecosystem that will allow me to do this?

```
(defn web-driver []
(taxi/set-driver! {:browser :chrome} "https://website.net")
(taxi/quick-fill-submit {"#user_email" "myemail@something.com"}
                      {"#user_password" "password"}
                      {"#user_password" taxi/submit})

(taxi/click "a[href*='/admin/...../export']")
(taxi/wait-until #(taxi/exists? {:xpath"/html/body/....}))
(taxi/click {:xpath "/html/body/...."})
(taxi/click {:xpath "/html/body/...."})
(taxi/click {:xpath "/html/body/...button"}))

(defn find-file []
(let [file-name (for [file (me/list-dir "/Users/.../Downloads")
            :let [s (.toString file)]
            :when (.contains s "Im looking for")] s)]
(apply str file-name)))
```

So I want to wait until after I run the webdriver for the download to complete before I call (find-file).  I am using selenium web-driver.

https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver

Comment: `ExecutorService#submit` will give you a `Future` to work with

Comment: What webdriver are you using? Does it offer this functionality, if so, you can just invoke that from Java.

Comment: What's with the down vote?  Just curious.....